There is an error while trying to load multiple files with Spark pypark
staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .option("inferSchema", "true")\
  .load("data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")


In the above code, there is this error:
Exception in thread "globPath-ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
If  I load only one file, there is no error.

Does this answer your question? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
